# Python | Google Appengine : What is the use of Key.from_path in Google Appengine? When to use it?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I've gone through the official documentation of Appengine and lot of answers on Stack overflow but I could not clearly get 'Key.from_path'does and when to appropriately use it. I feel glad if some one can provide me the details, possibly with an example.

Comment: The docs give a good example, and reason for use:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/keyclass#Key_from_path

You build this key, for example, when you want a fast, inexpensive way to retrieve that entity directly by key, without a query with filter.

Comment: This is all accurate, however it is part of `db` if you are starting out now and have no pre-existing code base then seriously consider using `ndb`, whilst the Key class doesn't have a method of that name, it does have a similiar method of key construction.  Read up on keys in general as this is usefull irrespective of the language or library you use to access the datastore.